# Trouble crawling html when it is not consistent

Tags: c#, html, csquery

I am new to csquery and I am having trouble crawling html like this below:

```
<li id="Ingredient">
    <span id="Amount" class="ingredient-amount">1 pound</span>
    <span id="Name" class="ingredient-name">sweet Italian Sausage
</li>
<li id="Ingredient">
    <span id="Amount" class="ingredient-amount">3/4 pound</span>
    <span id="Name" class="ingredient-name">lean ground beef</span>
</li>
```

I want to take out the text inside span tags and format them as follows:

```
1 pound sweet Italian sausage
3/4 pound lean ground beef
```

This is my code below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dom.Select("#Ingredient").Length; ++i) {
    if (dom.Select("#Ingredient span#Amount")[i] != null)
            Console.WriteLine(dom.Select("#Ingredient span#Amount")[i].InnerHTML + " ");
    if (dom.Select("#Ingredient span#Name")[i] != null)
            Console.WriteLine(dom.Select("#Ingredient span#Name")[i].InnerHTML);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

It works fine with the html above but the problem arises when one of the span is missing. For example if `<span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">sweet Italian sausage</span>` was missing from the html, my code would return:

```
1 pound lean ground beef
3/4 pound
```

As you can see, the `lean ground beef` went up. I want it to say with `3/4 pound` at all costs. And `1 pound` can stay alone.
How can I do that?
I have tried a lot of ways but it didn't work. So I want to do something like :
`for each "#Ingredient" write the "#Amount" if it exists or "#Name" if it exists. Do not bother with things on another Ingredient`

Comment: the html is invalid anyways. duplicate ids are not permitted, and your loop would only ever return the FIRST element with the matching id. if you work around that, then why even deal with the spans? Get the ingredient divs and extract the entirety of their innerText, which could give you '1 pound sweet italian sausage' already.

Comment: "and your loop would only ever return the FIRST element with the matching id" No. `dom.Select("#Ingredient span#Amount")` returns all elements with matching ids and I am using `[i]` to get the correct element.

Comment: I will try the second suggestion. Thanks

Comment: then c# is doing it wrong. a DOM id must be unique throughout the document. since it HAS to be unique, an id select should only ever return one element.

Comment: But @MarcB, how can I extract "1 pound sweet italian sausage" from `<span id="Amount" class="ingredient-amount">1 pound</span>
    <span id="Name" class="ingredient-name">sweet Italian Sausage</span>`? I have tried a lot of ways but non worked

Comment: Nevermind, I created a CQ object from the innerHTML of the "#ingredient" li